# Several fragments need location updates

Tags: java, android, oop, android-fragments

I'm messing around with an app which consists of two fragments, each in their own tab. One is a listfragment and the other is a mapfragment. Both fragments need location updates as location changes.

I'm reading [this](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) tutorial.

I'm wondering if I should implement this on the host activity and pass on the location to each fragment as the location updates. But I'm unsure about how to go about this. Because the listfragment would need to pass it on to the loader associated with the class.

Or implement the callbacks for each fragment and possible keep ErrorDialogFragment and servicesConnected as members of the host class? Or even in separate class? To avoid duplicated code.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the LocalBroadcastManager:

In each of your fragments that need this location, register a receiver for, say, action "LOCATION_WAS_JUST_UPDATED".

I am unsure where do you retrieve the location but it will work anyway. For example, if it is in a service, all you have to do is call:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(new Intent("LOCATION_WAS_JUST_UPDATED"));
```

You can of course pass the location in the bundle with this Intent or just set it in a persistent container and fragments that receive this broadcast can update their local location.

Comment: I retrieve the location on the main (host) activity. The LocalBroadcastManager does seem like a good idea. But I'm still a bit unsure how the program flow should be. Since on the host I should probably start some progressdialog which I should end in the individual fragment.

Comment: Well that is even simpler. You should implement a function getLocation in your Activity. Each activity should get the location when started using this function by using `getActivity`.`getLocation`. If the location is not available, show loader until the Broadcast is received. Or more simpler, just allow the activity to show loader and only show fragments when location is retrieved. You have too many options.